# I need a direction for a dynamic array

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula

I have a [simple formula](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18eH6APJwbV8x6iDpVxia-m1Ge90cIjC0Nu4QmEmbrM0/edit?usp=sharing):

```
 ={ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(
 IF('B-Prename5'!$B$2:$F$7<>""; 'B-Prename5'!$A$1&", "; )&
 IF('C-Prename9'!$B$2:$F$7<>""; 'C-Prename9'!$A$1&", "; )&
 IF('A-Prename10'!$B$2:$F$7<>""; 'A-Prename10'!$A$1; ); ", $"; ))}
```

And it works as intended. My challenge here is to make the numbers of input dynamical - depending on a list:

```
=filter(Names!G:G; len(Names!G:G))
```

I can't figure out if I'm suppose to use INDIRECT what ever to combine these two. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to use `INDIRECT`. You could just replace the references to the various tabs with the cells in your filtered list using the following formula.
*(Assuming the output of your filtered list is in column `P`)*

```
={
 ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(
 IF('B-Prename5'!$B$2:$F$7<>"", P1&", ", )&
 IF('C-Prename9'!$B$2:$F$7<>"", P2&", ", )&
 IF('A-Prename10'!$B$2:$F$7<>"", P3, ), ", $", ))}
```

Comment: Ah! I see what you mean but the challenge here is that the list of variables/names often differs. Some days it will produce 3 or 23 names and some of the names would be edited to. So I need "IF('B-Prename5'!$B$2:$F$7<>"", P1&", ", )&"-part to correspond with the actual and constantly updated list of names.

Comment: But `'B-Prename5'!$B$2:$F$7` is just one of the multiple variables you use in your formula. Using `INDIRECT` or whatever method to refer to your tabs would not make any difference. Anyway, I don't think your existing formula could be improved any further. Your data needs to be restructured. Or come up with a different formula altogether. Both options are not related to your original question.

Comment: Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it and even [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.

Comment: Ofc your answer is acceptable I'm just stuck and in doubt if i asked the right question :-)

Comment: I'm still wondering how to build a formula where 

This
={
 ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(

would turn this -> SORT(filter(Names!G2:G11; len(Names!G2:G11)); 1; TRUE)
into this ->
 IF('C-Prename9'!$B$2:$F$7<>""; 'C-Prename9'!$A$1&", "; )&
 IF('C-Prename3'!$B$2:$F$7<>""; 'C-Prename3'!$A$1; ); ", $"; 

))}